# Barplot Cluster with single colum in R Language

Tags: r

Is there an algorithm to create a layered barplot like this?

http://www.axiis.org/examples/HClusterColumnExample.html

Related question:
[2-layer barplot in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28724396/2-layer-barplot-in-r)

Answer (score 1):

Sure, there is a way to do it. But that would be quite non-standard. However, a good understanding of `barplot` will get you a long way:

```
# Create some toy data
set.seed(1)
n <- 100
df <- data.frame(F1 = sample(c("A", "B"), n, replace = TRUE), 
                 F2 = sample(c("c", "d"), n, replace = TRUE))
tab <- t(table(df))

# Create plot
barplot(colSums(tab), width = 2, space = 0.5)
barplot(tab, beside = TRUE, add = TRUE, col = rainbow(2), axisnames = TRUE)
legend("top", col = rainbow(2), pch = 15, legend = rownames(tab))
```

[image: Imgur]

Comment: Can you provide a counter-part method using ggplot2?

Comment: @lawyeR Unfortunately no, I'm not too savvy with `ggplot2`, so that would take me an unreasonably long time to do properly.